# How to update a JSON file from Unity and send it back to the server

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am a game developer, but I am new to web development with JSON. However, I am trying to learn how to implements an online high score system by using a JSON file stored on my web host server with a Unity project. So far, I can get user names and their scores from the remote JSON file by using the WWW class in Unity. However, I am not sure what would be the best way to update existing /add new pairs of data to the JSON file. I have been  seeking for proper documents/tutorials online for hours, but I didn't find one that works for me. Can anyone please provides some hints and suggestions for doing this from both client side(Unity) and server side? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check on the link below the library for JSON manipulation

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

> SimpleJSON is an easy to use JSON parser and builder.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject

> JSONObject : 
>   Decode JSON-formatted strings into a usable data structure, 
>   Encode structured data into a JSON-formatted string, 
>   Interoperable with Dictionary and WWWForm

Both libraries allows you to edit existing values and add new ones to your original JSON

To send your JSON back to the server you can use WWWForm : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html