# Mysql database alternatives if Mysql isn't an option

Tags: c#, mysql, json, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app using Unity. This app is supposed to upload certain simple information at specific points, which is why my original plan was to just connect it to a Mysql database. Unfortunately Unity doesn't support the NET 4.0 framework and nothing I've tried seems to work.

Yes I could use PHP scripts hosted on my web server to add and pull information, but I'd rather do it all from the app itself if at all possible.

The data I need to record is pretty simple, IDs, ints, strings, nothing too complex.

So I'm now trying to look into alternatives to Mysql.

## JSON

So far I have gotten SFTP to work (By using the `Renci.SshNet` library) and the app is now uploading files in my server's `home` directory. So my original idea was to just create **JSON** files with the data and edit them remotely.

Is this something that could be done with C#? How? Any specific resources?

The alternative to remote editing would be to download the JSON file, edit it locally, and then upload it again, but that doesn't sound like a very smart idea.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598610/how-to-update-a-json-file-from-unity-and-send-it-back-to-the-server) but it's unclear to me if it requires to send the whole JSON file to the server after every edit or if it's possible to just edit it from the app. Some clarification would be great.

## SQLlite

I've also looked into **SQLlite** but I'm also unsure if it could be remotely edited.

I've Googled it multiple times but can't really find any useful information.

What are my options at this point? What should I use if I needed the equivalent of a Mysql Database that can be remotely edited and read?

Comment: You sure you want to expose your database server username and password in a client side application?  You know disassemblers exists right?

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Use PHP scripts (or any stack) hosted on your server. There's also authentication and authorization to consider too.

Comment: Should I use PHP to upload images and files too then? I've been uploading that stuff through SFTP

Comment: @Eight correct, you absolutely should not be using SFTP either.  These are terribly insecure design strategies.  You cannot safely embed any kind of server credentials in an application, or trust any action your code in the application takes without server validation, because code running on a device is no longer under your control.  You need to creare an HTTPS API for all of your application's back-end interactions.

Comment: Are there any open source pre-made solutions that would allow me not to code the entire thing myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can start seeing into [Google Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com/)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start

But unity 2018.3 does support Net 4:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2017
https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2018/07/11/scripting-runtime-improvements-in-unity-2018-2/
https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/